# How to configure failover cluster to register its records automatically after it deleted from DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2016, failover, dns-zone

Windows Server 2016 failover cluster with two nodes.

Unfortunately the DNS record for the cluster name has been deleted and not created automatically.

How to configure failover cluster to register its records automatically? I tried to grant permission on DNS, but it didn't register the record in DNS automatically.

I can do it with PowerShell, but need it done automatically.

Comment: Why not set static records ?

Comment: The cluster is created it during configuration . and I configured dns to delete records that didn't update their records for 7 days .. unfortunately  cluster name and listener is deleted after enabling this option in dns .. can you explain  how dns automatically  register client for example if I put ip for pc and dns ( dc dns server) so its register automaticlly in dns records .. but if I deleted it .. it didn't  show again automatically .. so how I control it ?

Comment: That part automatically works "out of the box" without much administrative overhead. Unless something was intentionally done to the contrary. Does the zone allow updates ? That may be a problem.

Comment: yes , It allows update (secure and none secure) . if I updated IP address the record is updated automatically , but  I deleted it . it not created automatically .

Answer (score 0):

This question has a lot to do with debugging/analysis.

Is your `DNS-Client` service running?
Did you check if in the registry the `DisableDynamicUpdate` is set to `0`?
Check [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/enable-disable-dns-dynamic-registration).
In the network interface is the checkbox enabled to register the connection in DNS?
PowerShell for this: `Set-DnsClient -InterfaceIndex "Name Connection" -RegisterThisConnectionsAddress $true -UseSuffixWhenRegistering $true`

You can check here for more hits: [AD Dynamic DNS Updates not triggering on clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/749045/ad-dynamic-dns-updates-not-triggering-on-clients)